# Possible to gitignore variables?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project using an API that I would like to be able to upload to Github, but my code includes my private keys and secret tokens that I do not want uploaded. Is there a way to specifically exclude that information from being pushed while retaining the rest of the file?

Comment: Your secret information should be in an entirely separate *file*, and yes, it's possible to not commit that file. It's not possible to upload only part of a file.

Comment: Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754763/6309, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48449663/6309